# Laravel automatically add "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" to some certain columns

Tags: laravel, database-migration

My migration is like so:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->timestamp('from_date');
$table->timestamp('to_date');
$table->timestamps();
```

The problem is that when I migrate it, the second one which is `from_date` automatically gets `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute so it means when I update other columns this column will be updated too. That's what I don't want. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the DateTime column nullable, then MySQL won't add that. By default, MySQL adds that to the first timestamp in the table, unless explicitly told not to (via allowing a null value for the field). This is a MySQL thing, not a Laravel thing.

```
$table->timestamp('colName')->nullable();
```

**Read :**

[Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME - MYSQL DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

[Laravel & MySQL auto-adding “on update current_timestamp()” to timestamp fields](https://ma.ttias.be/laravel-mysql-auto-adding-update-current_timestamp-timestamp-fields/)

Source : [laracasts - How can I stop Laravel from making timestamps `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-can-i-stop-laravel-from-making-timestamps-on-update-current-timestamp?reply=408259)

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is native to MySQL. You can read about it on [this documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns have no automatic properties unless they are specified explicitly, with this exception: If the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` system variable is disabled, the first `TIMESTAMP` column has both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if neither is specified explicitly.

The docs go on to specify that there are two strategies for avoiding this behaviour:

- Enable the [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) variable in your database configuration.
- When defining your timestamp column, specify a `DEFAULT` or make the column nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `nullable` to the column in order to remove the constraint.

```
$table->timestamp('from_date')->nullable();
```

Unfortunately I think that this is the only solution. Then you can add a form validation in order to prevent setting `null` value for the field.

-- EDIT

```
$table->timestamp('from_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

// or
$table->timestamp('from_date')->useCurrent();
```

Try this as well, I believe this is what the `created_at` has.

Comment: But I think it is a bug, isn't it? Why the third one which is `to_date` doesn't take that attribute?

Comment: hm, that's weird. I really don't know the answer to that. Check my edit btw.